# Task schedular of laravel not working properly on server

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am able to execute individual artisan commands on server using putty cli. for eg.

```
php artisan inspire
```

and other custom commands related to database, they work fine while using putty. Also i put them in kernel.php 's schedule funtion like this

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->command('customcommand:execute')->everyMinute();
}
```

when i run this command using putty

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

it also works fine.
problem is that i am not able to execute schedule:run command via servers cron job.. command looks like this on server

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

funny thing is i am able to execute individual commands via servers cron job
i.e.

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On /path/to/artisan customcommand:execute >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

works as well...

only that schedule command is not working.

also it does not show any errors..

also if I dont add '-d register_argc_argv=On', i get exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

again here by server i mean cPanal, i have added this command under 'cron jobs'

Comment: `also it does not show any errors..` what do you expect if you redirect everything to /dev/null?

Comment: yes but even though i removed  '>> /dev/null 2>&1 ' it donst show any error. its running command.. i am geting email about that..showing no errors at all. only that 'Schedule' command is not performing anything, other commands are working.....

Answer (score 0):

The ini directive register_argc_argv was disabled on the php.ini and I needed to enable it explicitly on each call in order to accept `argc` and `argv` parameters. Luckily I easily solved this problem using `exec` instead of `command`

```
$schedule->exec('php -d register_argc_argv=On /path/to/artisan sms:bulk-send')
```

Use your command instead of `sms:bulk-send` Then it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php71 /home/your_domain/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

first , 
`which php` 
to get which php you're using now

then change your cron job command like
`* * * * * /path/to/your/php /path/to/your/project/artisan schedule:run`
specify which php and project you are using
for example `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/project/artisan schedule:run`

it works for me